# Do I need to format any drive for installing Ubuntu?

Tags: format

I just wanted to try Ubuntu and I downloaded the .iso file.
I want to have both windows and Linux on my PC and although I read the tutorials and other topics in the site, I didn't get the answer to one question.

For installing it alongside Windows (assume that Windows is in drive C), and not installing it in the same drive, But in drive G for example, do I have to format that drive or that will not be necessary? ( the other drive is in NTFS format)

When we are "selecting drive", does it mean selecting one of C or D or ... partitions?
And what does the space allocation means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to install Ubuntu *alongside* Windows on a partition you will need to format your partition. Ubuntu uses the ext3 or etx4 format, unlike Windows which uses NTFS. The installer will handle the formatting.

If you have multiply hardrives in your computer you will need to select which disk you would like to install to, otherwise "selecting drive" refers to partitions.

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 you can use [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) to install Ubuntu on a virtual partition within Windows, however this method is not recommended.

If you just want to *try* Ubuntu temporarily you can run a live session, running it off of a [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) (which you create when you burn the ISO to a disk) and play around with it without touching your existing Windows installation. Just select "Try Ubuntu without installing" after booting your installation disk/LiveCD.

So to answer your question you *will* need to format drive `G:` as ext3/4 before installing, which the installer will manage. "selecting drive" usually means selecting a partition to install Ubuntu onto.

Space allocation will depend on how your drives are configured and what installation method you are using, however "space allocation" in the general term means how much space you give Ubuntu to be installed on and use.

See also: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks.If I want to install it on another partition i should choose " Install alongside windows" ? And as it is in a different partition from the one windows is installed in , will it still be dual boot?

Comment: @ahmadrezamostajabi What version of Ubuntu are you installing?

Comment: I want to install ubunto Desktop 13.04 64-bit

Comment: @ahmadrezamostajabi The "install alongside windows" option was removed in 13.04, you will need to choose "something else" and pick your partitions.

Comment: I tried this but i got some problem in the partitions part.As i could only install it in the drive my windows was installed in and in another one  in which all other partitions i had, had been merged into one and i couldn't just format that.It also showed me two partitions with 100 and 1 MB space.

Comment: @ahmadrezamostajabi What are your problems?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu it will format the partition for you to the Ext4 file system.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot up from the Live CD and pick "install", you will get to choose whether you'd like to clean your entire drive and just install Ubuntu, if you'd like to install it along side your current OS, or if you'd like to configure it your self with the built-in disk partitioning system. Don't be afraid of launching it and have a look. It will not install before you tell it to :)

as mentioned by Joren, it will convert one partition to ext.

Best of luck!